# How to show hide a text field when something is selected from a drop down.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

My question is, if I select something in my drop down like ABS when ABS is selected how can I have a text box show up for additional information to input. What I have now isn't working...Any help is much appreciated!

This is my app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#indirect_id').change(function() {
    var indirect_id = $(this).val();
    if(indirect_id == 'ABS'){
      $('#sick_comment').show();
    }
    else{
      $('#sick_comment').hide();
    }
  });
```

This is my view

```
.row-fluid
  =simple_form_for @entry, :url => url_for(:controller => 'entry', :action => 'create'), :method => :post do |f|

%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
  %th.lt Indirect Code:
  %td.lt= f.input_field :indirect_id, :as => :select, :label => false, :collection => ['PD', 'VAC', 'ABS'], :id => 'indirect_id', :input_html => {:value => ''}


  %th.lt Optional Comment
  %td.lt= f.text_field :sick_day,  :label => false, :id => 'sick_comment', :input_html => {:value => ''}

%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
= f.button :submit, "Submit", :class => 'btn btn-primary', :style => 'margin-left:50px;'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the full text of your app.js, then you are missing an end bracket and parenthesis:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#indirect_id').change(function() {
        var indirect_id = $(this).val();
        if(indirect_id == 'ABS'){
          $('#sick_comment').show();
        }
        else{
          $('#sick_comment').hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: I forgot those . But still no luck getting this to work @BenJaspers

Comment: Is the textbox never shown? I suspect this `:input_html => {:value => ''}` might be setting the value of all your options to the empty string.

Comment: Are you going to post how you fixed it??